# How to make selected in the year option with php?

Tags: php, html-select, selectedvalue

I want to make the selected in the year option with PHP, but my coding is not working. For example, if I want the selected year is 2019, then the option will show 2019 selected at first. Hope someone can guide me on which part I am getting wrong. Thanks.

Below is my coding:

```html
<select id="year" class="form-control" name="year" title="Year">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>

<?php
$result_arr_['year'] = "2019";
if($result_arr_['year'] == true){
    $selected_year = "selected";
}else{
    $selected_year = " ";
}

for ($year = (int)date('Y'); 1900 <= $year; $year--): ?>
    <option value="<?=$year;?>" <?php echo $selected_year;?>><?=$year;?></option>
<?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

My output just show me start with the 1900 year, not 2019.

[image: output]

Comment: Of course `$result_arr_['year'] == true` is true, because you just assigned a truth-y value (the string value `2019`)  right before that line … The whole code makes little sense. This check belongs _inside_ your loop over all the years, not once before it.

Comment: If you look at your source, everything is selected. That's because you're settling the variable before your loop, and it's if 2019 is true (spoiler, it is).

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your comment. Do you have any idea to make a selected year?

Comment: @aynber You are right. I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to test each date generated by the loop, inside the loop

```
<select id="year" class="form-control" name="year" title="Year">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>

<?php
$result_arr_['year'] = "2019";

for ($year = (int)date('Y'); 1900 <= $year; $year--): 
    $selected = $result_arr_['year'] == $year ? " selected='selected' " : '';
?>
    <option value="<?=$year;?>" <?= $selected;?>><?=$year;?></option>
<?php
endfor;
?>
</select>
```